# How do i delete every role in a server?

Tags: discord.py

i am trying to find out how to delete every role in a server. I cant find anything on it on the internet, so i am coming here. Basically i need to get a piece of code that just deletes every role in a server with one command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do [for loops](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/) and loop over guild roles then deleting every role. Example

```
for roles in ctx.guild.roles:
    if role.name != "role name that you want to exclude":
        pass
    else:
        await roles.delete(reason="Reason Here")
await ctx.send("Deletion Complete.", delete_after=3)
```

Check the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20role#discord.Guild.roles) for ctx.guild.roles,
and check the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=delete#discord.Role.delete) for delete()